# Application icons not showing in window buttons item in xfce panel

Tags: xubuntu, icons, xfce, xfce-panel

The icons for some applications are not being displayed properly on the window buttons item in the xfce panel. On the screenshot below, you can see the sound settings icon perfectly but the icon for the lollypop music player is not being displayed. Specifically, I am facing this problem with lollypop, sublime text and foxit reader. I was wondering if there is any way for me to manually assign icons for these applications.

[image]

*I have checked the .desktop files for these applications and they contain the icon image.

Comment: +1 Same here. Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: I have the same issue with Slack. The icon shows up in the panel indicator plugin but not in the windows button or Alt+tab

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue while using the Obsidian App via AppImage. Below are my Desktop entry based on the actual AppImage location:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Obsidian
Exec=/opt/obsidian/obsidian.AppImage
Icon=obsidian
StartupWMClass=obsidian
Terminal=false
```

```
/opt
  |
  |----/obsidian
         |
         |--- obsidian.AppImage
         |--- obsidian.png
```

I was still facing the issue related to missing icons in both `xfce-panel` and the application switcher. After coming across this [post](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-calendar/-/issues/306), I added the icon (the same one which is present in `/opt/obsidian/` inside the `apps` folder of my icon theme as shown below:

```
.icons/Os-Catalina-icons-master/128x128/apps/obsidian.png
.icons/Os-Catalina-icons-master/22x22/apps/obsidian.png
.icons/Os-Catalina-icons-master/64x64/apps/obsidian.png
```

Followed by a restart, solved the issue.